# Import Address Book from Gmail/Hotmail/Yahoo using C# and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, import, addressbook

Hi can somebody tell me how to import all of my contacts from gmail, yahoo, hotmail and so on.. and i want to send an invitation for all my contacts?

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Check the .NET Address Book API's of those providers:

- [Google Contacts Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/code.html)

  - [Retrieving contacts](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_all_contacts) (C#)
- [Windows Live Contacts API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/live)

  - [Code samples](http://isdk.dev.live.com/ISDK.aspx) (C#)
- [Yahoo! Address Book API](http://developer.yahoo.com/addressbook/)

  - [Yahoo! Web Service REST Calls](http://developer.yahoo.com/dotnet/howto-rest_cs.html) (C#)
  - [Contacts API URI](http://developer.yahoo.com/social/rest_api_guide/contacts-resource.html)