# How to get address book from Yahoo Mail through .NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, yahoo

I need to get friends list (from address book) from Yahoo Mail. How can I do do this in VB.NET?

Comment: have done any research on Google?

Comment: i got code to get access addressbook of gmail and its working fine.

Comment: yes... i got lots of code from google.. but all are not working

Comment: i got gmail code from google also which are working fine but for yahoo its not working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085498/import-address-book-from-gmail-hotmail-yahoo-using-c-sharp-and-asp-net do refer this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should try using Search a little more...

http://www.bing.com/search?q=yahoo+contacts+api&qs=RQ&form=QBRE&pq=yahoo+contactapi&sc=1-16&sp=1&sk=
Top Answer...

http://developer.yahoo.com/social/contacts/