# Importing MSN and Yahoo contacts

Tags: c#, asp.net, yahoo, msn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Import Address Book from Gmail/Hotmail/Yahoo using C# and ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085498/import-address-book-from-gmail-hotmail-yahoo-using-c-sharp-and-asp-net)

i want to get list of contacts when user enters his yahoo or msn alike emails. Application is build in ASP.NET with 3.5 framework. Solution i've found on this site does not work or require framework 4.0. I don't need solution which costs money or not personally tested by you ones.

thanks

Comment: With this kind of functionality we (developers) are teaching users that it's quite alright to hand their passwords to 3rd parties. I know that this kind of setup is increasingly used, but I have a big problem with implementations where the password passes to a 3rd party.

Comment: @spender, In my case this intended to ease on dumb end user who has popup blocker which will in fact block solution with tokens, though i don't mind working with tokens from Yahoo or MSN. Just those two fail to write proper implementation of their API while Google's solution took me 5 minutes to setup.

Comment: use socialauth.net you can download it from http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-net/