# Import yahoo contacts from yahoo credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, contacts, yahoo

I want to import yahoo contacts from yahoo credentials. In my application user will enter the credentials and his contacts should be imported. How can I do it ? I have already looked this
[Import Address Book from Gmail/Hotmail/Yahoo using C# and ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085498/import-address-book-from-gmail-hotmail-yahoo-using-c-and-asp-net)

but this does not helped much. Is there any rest call to yahoo by which I can import contacts ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is standard library. What is problem with this:**

- [Yahoo! Contacts API](http://developer.yahoo.com/social/contacts/)

**Here are some examples using Yahoo Address Book API:**

- [Fetch Contacts From yahoo using asp.net and c#](http://www.zoomasp.net/Yahoo_Contact_Importer_csharp.aspx)
- [Yahoo! Contact Import class in C#](http://gnillydev.blogspot.com/2007/10/yahoo-contact-import-class-in-c.html)

**For Gmail:**

[Gmail Agent API v0.5 / Mail Notifier & Address Importer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/gmailagent.aspx)

Comment: Yahoo's Address Book API is deprecated in favour of their Contacts API. Best to avoid this one.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [SocialAuth.NET](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-net/)

They cover all the social service providers, including Yahoo!.