# Yahoo contacts api asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, contacts, yahoo

I am trying to get yahoo contacts, but its not working for me.

Found some code from  http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencontactsnet/

I am using asp.net 2008.

Please let me know if you have any other way to get the contacts.

Also, i have tried to use http://developer.yahoo.com/social/contacts/, bu the create project link is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Did you look here [Import Address Book from Gmail/Hotmail/Yahoo using C# and ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085498/import-address-book-from-gmail-hotmail-yahoo-using-c-and-asp-net) or you have any other problems (as you said not working for me)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [SocialAuth.NET](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-net/)

They cover all the social service providers like Gmail, Hotmail, Yahoo, LinkedIn, Twitter etc.